# Run arbitrary ruby code during puppet execution?

Tags: puppet, facter

I'm working on extending the [puppetlabs-mongodb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb) module to allow for [user authentication](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mongodb/issues/36). The challenge is that mongo changed its mechanism for enabling user authentication between version [2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-authentication/) and version [2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and so distinct code must be run in order to give a user authentication credentials to a database.

My initial thought was to create a custom facter fact that basically captured the output of `mongod --version`, but it appears that facter facts are loaded *before* the puppet manifest is executed. Is there a way to execute arbitrary code *at run time* during puppet execution so that I can access `mongod --version` and decide which method to use to enable user authentication?

> **Note:** One approach would be to have puppet run a single script to create user credentials and have the script detect the `mongod --version` at runtime. This doesn't seem like a very puppet-y way of doing things, but perhaps I am off base on that. What is the best way to handle the need for accessing variables dynamically in puppet/facter?

Answer (score 2):

The [word from @puppetlabs](https://twitter.com/deanmalmgren/status/356795407659044867) is that you can not run ruby code (or any other code) dynamically during a puppet run. The "right" way to do this is in the note above with an `exec` statement that dynamically checks for the mongodb version. For details on the implementation, see [manifests/add_user.pp](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/puppetlabs-mongodb/blob/527742bc49677153e8aabde81f8137aebfc0ab8a/manifests/add_user.pp) and the associated [templates/add_user*.erb](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/puppetlabs-mongodb/tree/527742bc49677153e8aabde81f8137aebfc0ab8a/templates).

If anyone has a more "puppety" method for accomplishing this, I'd love to learn about it!

Answer (score 1):

Just put your Ruby code in a ERB template and use `template("${module_name}/templ.erb")` to return your version string.